# How to take event from web-components in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, web-component

I want to use web-components in agnularjs project.
How can I take events from web-components.
I was using `ng-click` for `mwc-checkbox`, for example.
But I think better handle the event of change and I don`t know how to make it.
How does it receive events from web-components?
Where can I find out about it?

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('appDir', appDir);

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'),
  ['app']
);

function appDir() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'app-dir.directive.html',
    link: function appDirLinkFn($scope) {
      $scope.checked = false;
      $scope.toggleHandler = function toggleHandler() {
        $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">

<app-dir></app-dir>
<script
  type="text/ng-template"
  id="app-dir.directive.html"
>
  <mwc-checkbox
    ng-prop-checked="checked"
    ng-click="toggleHandler()"
  ></mwc-checkbox>
  <mwc-button
    ng-click="toggleHandler()"
  >Toggle</mwc-button>
  <span ng-bind="checked"></span>
</script>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@next/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@material/mwc-button@^0.1.0/mwc-button.js?module"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@material/mwc-checkbox@^0.1.0/mwc-checkbox.js?module"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

web components are like pure Html element so they trigger pure DOM event. in order to handle pure DOM event in Agularjs you can use **[ngOn](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOn)** directive.

```
<button ng-on-pureEventName="f()" >click  here</button>
```

**Update**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('appDir', appDir);

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'),
  ['app']
);

function appDir() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'app-dir.directive.html',
    link: function appDirLinkFn($scope) {
      $scope.checked = false;
      $scope.toggleHandler = function toggleHandler($event) {
        $scope.checked = !$event.target.checked;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">

<app-dir></app-dir>
<script
  type="text/ng-template"
  id="app-dir.directive.html"
>
  <mwc-checkbox
    ng-prop-checked="checked"
    ng-on-input="toggleHandler($event)"
  ></mwc-checkbox>
  <mwc-button
    ng-click="toggleHandler()"
  >Toggle</mwc-button>
  <span ng-bind="checked"></span>
</script>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@next/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@material/mwc-button@^0.1.0/mwc-button.js?module"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@material/mwc-checkbox@^0.1.0/mwc-checkbox.js?module"></script>
```

It seems that [material-components-web-components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components) don't have suitable documentation. I could hardly realize in an [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/issues/49) that onChange event is triggered by **onInput** event name.

I hope this will help you

Comment: thank you for attention. I tried `ng-on-change`, but it was unsuccessful. Are you can tell me about where or how can be to know pure event name for specific web-components?

Comment: In https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/blob/master/packages/checkbox/src/mwc-checkbox.ts I did not find, where this web-compoment dispatch  event.  To my regret `ng-on-input` not fired function too

Comment: what do you mean "ng-on-input not fired function" ?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/issues/63